# JPA never call update, but persist work

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm encountering a problem with JPA. I have three entities; the first (Event) works fine. I present only the header:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({EventSupervisionListener.class})
public class Event extends Exportable {
// Some code
```

The second extends the first and implements a interface. This one doesn't work very well. I can persist a new entity, but the update method doesn't work.

```
@Entity
public class RemoteEvent extends Event implements RemoteEntity {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private Remote net;

    @Override
    public Remote getRemote() {
        return cellnet;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRemoteCellNet(Remote net) {
        this.net= net;
    }
}
```

Finally the remote entity, which also works fine:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({RemoteListener.class})
public class Remote extends Device  {
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, optional=true, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private RemoteArea remoteRootArea;
    // A lots of contain but no reference with RemoteEvent or Event
```

For the update I have a simple method:

```
// Get a event object :
RemoteEvent event = getEvent();
em.find(RemoteEvent.class, event.getId());
// Event is find (test with em.contain).
event.setName("test");
```

That's not working; I cannot understand why...

Thanks for helping

[EDIT new contents after some research]

I have simplify the problem and focus on the method who create the error. I have this easy hierarchy :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Exportable implements Serializable, UUIDOwner {

@Entity
@EntityListeners({EventSupervisionListener.class})
public class Event extends Exportable {

@Entity
public class RemoteEvent extends Event{
// This entity do nothing except extend Event.
```

The problem seem to come from this part of Event, in debug mode i can reach @postLoad method, but the onUpdate is never call. I can bypass the problem with comment the json
part of loadImageGroup method.

```
@Lob
private String images;

@ExtJsSerialize
private transient List<EventImageGroup> imageGroupList = new ArrayList<EventImageGroup>();

@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
private void saveImageGroups() {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    for (EventImageGroup imgGroup : imageGroupList) {
        json.put(imgGroup.toJson());
    }
    images = json.toString();
}

@PostLoad
private void loadImageGroups() {
    try 
    {
        imageGroupList.clear();
        // If i comment this instruction the code working fine. 
        // There are no exception rise.
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(images);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i) { 
            imageGroupList.add(new EventImageGroup(json.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    } 
    catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Event1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I precise i have exactly the same value in database for a event object and a remoteEvent except the dtype.

I can't understand why a extends without any change can lead to problem...

Thanks

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please do not forget to mark it an accepted (not necessarily mine).

Comment: @Manticore: Shouldn't you use `eventDb.setName("test");` instead as described in Andrei's answer? Remember that you need to update the entity that has been returned from `find()` method. As for the error message - looks like you call `find()` inside JTA transaction so explicit `commit()` is forbidden. Try to remove `begin()` and `commit()` methods.

Comment: Yes i do. In fact i have try the simple case, just get a event with find(Event.class, hardcodedId); and permorm change on event. That's work for all my entities except RemoteEvent. I suppose that's come from relation with the entity Remote but i can't focus the problem.

Comment: if you are getting "Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA" it means you are using JTA and cannot use EntityTransactions.  How are you obtaining your EntityManager and associating it to the JTA transaction?  What does em.flush() do after the change?

Comment: You should also correct the code in the question, as you seem to be calling event.setName("test"); when it should be eventDb.setName("test");.  It also seems you are getting a different class since RemoteEvent is !=RemoveEvent used in the find call.

Answer (score 1):

That is because simply calling `find()` does not mark your instance `event` managed: any changes you make on that instance are not tracked/recognized by your JPA provider. In order to fix that, you should do the changes on the returned entity:

```
// Get a event object :
RemoteEvent event = getEvent();
RemoveEvent eventDb = em.find(RemoveEvent.class, event.getId());
eventDb.setName("test");//note here the returned instance is used
//DO NOT FORGET TO COMMIT if necessary
```

Comment: I would like to add my 2 cents. This solution is OK from a technical perspective, but if a method called `getEvent` returns an unmanaged entity with a primary key, then there is something wrong with the architecture. I suspect the entity classes are leaking into the service layer. That is indeed a very bad design.

Comment: In fact the method getEvent doesn't exist. That's just a simplification of the design because event id come from network.

Comment: @mwhs you are right. Very often I do not get very deep into details, as it is counter-productive to start digging and asking additional questions.